# Seleção com Dapper usando cláusula IN

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

A minha ideia é gerar uma pesquisa no meu banco usando a cláusula `in` através do **Dapper**. Por exemplo:

```
select * from product
where CasNo in(@filtro)
```

Lembrando que dentro desse `@filtro` tem uma lista de **CasNo** que é do tipo `List<String>`.

**Testes**

```
List<Product> IProductRepository.RetornarPesquisaProdutos(List<string> filtroId) =>
    conn.Query<Product>(
        @"
        SELECT 
            pr.IdProduct as IdProduct, 
            pr.Name as Name,
            sup.Name as Supplier,
            sup.IdSupplier as IdSupplier
        FROM Product pr    
            FULL OUTER JOIN Supplier AS sup ON (pr.IdSupplier = sup.IdSupplier)
        where
            pr.IdProduct in (@filtroId) or
            pr.CASNo     in (@filtroId)
        ORDER BY pr.CommercialName",
        param: new { filtroId }).ToList();
```

Isso não deu certo.

Também tentei fazer como eu passava no ADO.NET (que deu certo lá, porém era de uma forma muito escrota que eu tinha feito) concatenando direto nesta lista todos os itens que eu precisava. Exemplo `filtro = "'123-1', '326-3', '684-8'");` e mandava esse filtro direto na minha Query **sem** fazer o `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(filtro);`.

Porém agora eu preciso fazer no Dapper essa ideia de passar uma lista dentro do IN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só tirar os parênteses. O Dapper já faz isso.

```
select * from product
where CasNo in @filtro
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!